# Get data from mysql database table without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a select box(list box) where it has 3 values drop down like Pending,Approve,NotApproved and when I select any one of them I want to fire a query so that I get data from database
like `select * from table where status="Pending"` without reloading page.

can any one help me how can I get data from database without page refresh in a php file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use Ajax https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you can find many tutorials on the web

Comment: that is what AJAX is for. Learn how to implement it, using jQuery plugin it is easy.

Comment: Also, if you want to learn something cool, Angularjs is also great for that.

Comment: @Lorenzo Why Jquery or any other framework and why not simple javascript to begin with?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal yes he can use whatever he wants. Jquery is an option. I f you have other suggestion why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a get or post AJAX request like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml/html/script/json/jsonp', // I guess html will be do or JSON if you are returning in a JSON format
  data: {param1: 'value1'}, // Here you can send any additional parameters like status ( pending etc.)
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
    // in the data variable you will receive the data from your PHP file if the request was succesfull
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX for this (as is said in comments). You have can use :

- XmlHttpRequest,
- [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) : Less code than an ordinary XmlHttpRequest and easier to implement. Perfect for beginner but heavy if you are looking for performance (to my mind),

And some libraries that I don't know.